# Importing libraries

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I have a general question using third party libraries, but I will exemplify it on two examples to make it clearer and more "answerable":

I want to use pyfmi in Python. Trying to install it through pip tells me:

"Exception: FMI Library cannot be found. Please specify its location, either using the flag to the setup script '--fmil-home' or specify it using the environment variable FMIL_HOME."

I figured out that I had to download the tar.gz from jmodelica.org and extract the files, create a build directory, use cmake, make and make install commands. All runs through without a hitch. But trying to install through pip gives me the same error message. So my question is:

How does one do this? Do they mean by setup script the setup.py file? How can I access that one if I am installing through pip? 
An which one is the fmi home directory? Is it the untarred file in my Downloads-Folder or one of the files in it:

```
  builddir
  Config.cmake
  install
  src
  Test
  ThirdParty
  CMakeLists.txt
  FMILIB_Acknowledgements.txt
  FMILIB_License.txt
  FMILIB_Readme.txt
  LICENSE.md
  README.md
```

? What is that flag and where to put it "exactly".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyFMI requires (as noted on the PyPI site) that FMI Library is installed prior to trying to install PyFMI from source.

During the installation (invoking python setup.py install) of PyFMI, the environment variable "FMIL_HOME" is checked to see if that points to an installation of FMI Library, if so, this will be used during the installation. So in your case, you need to set this environment variable. The other option is to install manually (using python setup.py install --fmil-home="/path/to/fmil") where the added path should point to FMI Library.

The third option is to see if there are binary installers for your platform (these include FMIL). Check PyPI, Anaconda and Christoph Gohlke's site.